# Cannot push to remote repository (git)

Tags: git, push, public-key

I don't know if it's just me, but I find the process of interacting with remote repositories of Git via command line utterly frustrating. I have generated my own SSH key, added it to my GitLab account. And I have the same key saved, just checked to be sure. And yet, if I try to:

```
git push origin master
```

of course being in the proper `git` folder, the only thing I get is the infamous:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does `ssh -Tv git@<yourGitlabServer>` work? By "proper git folder", you you mean in `myrepo` or in `myrepo\.git`?

Comment: No, it didn't work. And I meant `myrepo`

Comment: What GIt version are you using? What OS are you on?

Comment: 1.9.4, and it's sadly Windows 8

Comment: Can you check if the environment variable `HOME` is defined? (just type `set HOME`) Do you see your public and private ssh keys (`id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`) in `dir `%HOME%\.ssh`

Comment: I don't know how gitlab recommends settng up ssh, but the one I've found works is ssh's native configuration file, `~/.ssh/config`.  Here's mine for github:

`Host github.com  \n HostName github.com \n User git \n IdentityFile /home/jthill/.ssh/id_rsa \n`

with newlines where the \n's are and I can use `ssh://github.com/$me/$repo` for a git remote url.  Try putting the spot you saved your generated keys in for an IdentityFile in that.

Comment: And what should this variable be set to?

Comment: The keys I generated were saved in my repo location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you launch your Git with `<path\to\git1.9.4>\git-cmd.bat`: it will define `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`.

Then make sure your public (`id_rsa.pub`) and private (`id_rsa`) ssh keys are in `%HOME\.ssh`

A `ssh -Tv git@<gitlabserver>` should then work (unless your private key is passphrase protected).

Comment: I couldn't find this `.bat` file, so I set the variable manually. And I'm 100% sure the key files are in the `.ssh` folder. Still not working though.

Comment: @Ok, try with a PATH set to a minimum: `set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;<path\to\git1.9.4>\bin`.

Comment: Okay, reset the key pairs at both sides did the trick. Still no idea what caused the problem though. Thanks

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Excellent. By the way, Git for Windows is now 2.4.0 https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases. No setup needed: just uncompress  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.0.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.0.2-dev-preview-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want and add that to the PATH.